# Populate The Custom Yum Repository with list

Tags: linux, yum

I have a list of 350 rpms listed in a text file that are also installed in a cluster that is not online with the outside world.  We have an internal yum repository.  Is there a way to take the list, and download all the 350 installs for yum to bring back to the cluster?  I hate thinking of downloading them one by one.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, yum install xxxx-downloadonly will download, I just need to make a script that will read from the text file list of rpms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reposync and making internal repos. (and then using kickstart) is better option, IMO.
 But if you want to just download, then something as simple as:

```
yumdownloader $(cat myfile)
```

...might well do it. yumdownloader is in the yum-utils package. If you need to use yum/yum-downloadonly then you can do:

```
yum --installroot=/tmp/my-installroot --downloadonly install $(cat myfile)
```

...that will get you all the deps. too (not sure if that's what you want). If it doesn't fit on the command use yum shell:

```
perl -pe 's/^/install /' myfile > myfile-shell
echo run >> myfile-shell
yum --installroot=/tmp/my-installroot --downloadonly shell myfile
```

...but again, I think you really want to have usable repos. on your yum machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yum install `cat /path/to/pkgs_list`
```